# iPhone UITableView : How to remove the spacing between sections in group style table?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I am creating a table view in which there are 10 sections, all having a header view but no cells. So, in short, my table view will display 10 header views only; there will be no cells in any section. Now when I do that there is some space between the section's header views. I want to remove that space. Is that possible? Can you provide me with some hint or work around to achieve this?

Here are the data source methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return 10;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return 0;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    return label;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 44.0f;
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the output: 
[image]

I have a bit of a complex reason why I am doing it like this, that I wont be able to explain through writing. All I want to do is have no spacing in the section's header views. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want 10 section headers and ***no*** cells?  How about just doing a table view with 10 cells that look like section headers?

Comment: @maddy I understand using 10 cells would solve it but as I mentioned the reason I am using header views is bit complex that I can not explain . I have created an expandable cell kind of view . Again its not exactly like just expandable but has got so many other constraints .

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try this..

```
   self.tableView.rowHeight = 0; // in viewdidload
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone]; // in viewdidload

 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 0.01f;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return <your header height>;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return <your header view>;
}
```

Also have table seprator as none.

Comment: Why can't it just be 0?

Answer (score 23):

If you return `0` in `tableView:heightForFooterInSection:` than default value is returned (probably 10.0). It is tricky, but you can use `CGFLOAT_MIN` instead of `0` to remove footer.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}
```

*Update:*

**Swift 3**:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it directly within the interface, you have to set the footer height to 1 like this :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try with following code

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.25; // as for you need
}
```

you can also manage by following delegate method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Is short you can manage it by above two method.

Comment: Interesting. I just tried and implementing the `heightForFooterInSection` does have some impact on the spacing between group sections but you can't remove the space completely.

Comment: @iPatel actually if you return 0 from - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section then it still creates the footer space with default height , so instead of 0 you will have to return 0.01 , thats a negligible height footer . This works .

Answer (score 3):

The grouped style tableview has a default footer, you should also custom the footer to overwrite it

or

try the plain style.

```
typedef enum {
   UITableViewStylePlain,
   UITableViewStyleGrouped
} UITableViewStyle;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the Table View style from Grouped to Plain. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

So I can not up vote but I can post a reply

The correct answer to this way in fact

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use method heightForHeaderInSection . You can also change it depending on different sections for eg. at some sections you may need to show more distance & under some, you don't want to show gap. For such case you can use CGFLOAT_MIN which is 0.000001f. Giving you an example, how you can use different section with different header heights

> ```
> - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
> {
>     if (section == 0 || section == 2)
>     {
>         return 55.0;
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         return CGFLOAT_MIN;
>     }
> }
> ```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

if you use tableview with **.grouped style**, maybe you should set header delegate method like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return .leastNormalMagnitude
}
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return UIView()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   return 0;
}
```

As mentioned in comments, try using this :

```
 self.tableView.rowHeight = 0;
```

Comment: Instead of this just call `self.tableView.rowHeight = 0;`.